# Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Камера?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Камера?

Answer (score 1):

**Скорее всего, фамилия склоняется при безударном окончании**

Розенталь  [XXXVI. ФОРМЫ ИМЕН СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm)

Из фамилий **на ударяемые** -а **склоняются только славянские**: У писателя Майбороды, к философу Сковороде, фильмы Александра Митты.

Нерусские фамилии **на неударяемые -о, -я** (в основном славянские и романские) **склоняются**, например: творчество Яна Неруды, стихи Пабло Неруды,  утопизм Кампанеллы.

Не склоняются также финские фамилии на -а: встреча с Куусела.

Колебания наблюдаются в употреблении фамилий грузинских, японских и некоторых других; ср.: ария в исполнении Зураба Соткилава, песни Окуджавы, произведения Рюноске Акутагавы.

В последние годы явно наметилась тенденция к склонению подобных фамилий.